# How to find associated date(x axis) with max value(y axis) in d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have **[this](https://bl.ocks.org/LemoNode/ed1b5bfc5b7356ae7313cf78f0e75518)** **(SOLVED)** chart where i want to find the x coordinates for the corresponding max/min value on the y axis.(and display em on the line chart as I've already started to do)

I've managed to find the coordinates for the y axis and it updates accordingly, but I'm not sure how I would find the corresponding date to the max/min value.

I tried using the `d3.nest` function and associate the max/min value to it's date and tried to assign it to a single key but wasn't sure how to go about it or whether it was the right approach to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier approach is simply finding the object with the highest value:

```
var maximumObj = data.filter(e => e[city] === maximum)[0];
```

And using it to plot a circle or anything you want.

Check the bl.ocks: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/b388c8557f4210b66f8eae25b436f4f3

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!